# OpenGL and C++: Real-Time Handling and Binding Buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have been toying with OpenGL for about 2 weeks, creating hardcoded VBOs and making rotating triangles, but the question that has been lingering in my head is how the heck do I create more than one VBO/VAO in real-time so I can handle multiple objects?  And how do I render multiple objects on the screen?  The binding system seems limiting and restrictive.  Eventually, I want to be able to create objects and draw them using a single Lua function.  Sorry for the no-code post, but I have no code to begin with as I am trying to figure this out conceptually.

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to go from one VBO/VAO to multiple. In your rendering function you bind the particular VAO for your object and then make a draw call (glDraw*). Then you bind the next VAO and make another draw call. You can even draw the same object multiple times and just update the transformation matrices in between.

Comment: Thanks, so would I use a function to bind and draw an object's VAO/VBO?  But another problem I have is that the VBO has to be declared before use.  So when I use an obj loader, how do I do this without hardcoding it in the program and have the VBO created upon loading the model?  Sorry if this is a newbish question,I am just a sophmore in high school trying to get a head start in graphical programming.

Comment: The "binding system" is how all of traditional OpenGL works. You bind objects to locations with special meaning and then subsequent commands will access a certain set of them. More accurately, it is called "selector/latch". The alternative design would have you pass the name of relevant object(s) directly to GL commands, and this can be seen in this under-implemented extension: [GL_EXT_direct_state_access](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_direct_state_access.txt). That is similar to how D3D works, by the way, so do not get the idea that all graphics APIs work like GL.

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up a bit more.  So if a certain set of objects can be accessed by certain locations, would it be acceptable (and possible) to make a class containing GL binding functions to simplify it?

Comment: Yes, and in fact this is precisely what VAOs are designed to do. They store all of the vertex pointers as well as the buffer object that is currently bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` such that changing the bound VAO will set all of these states in a single operation. The buffer object that is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is only used when you call `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` so that binding is not stored by VAOs. VAOs only store the pointer(s) that you setup using that command. `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is a little bit different, `glDrawElements (...)` uses it everytime you call it.

Comment: So, from what I understand, VAOs are pretty much pointers and VBOs contain vertex data.  I'm on my way to making a very simple game "engine" (doubt I'd call it that).  But this cleared up a lot for me.  How do I give you rep, I'm new at SO.

Comment: I would have to write an answer and have you accept it, but I am not entirely sure what the question was to be honest ;) I will take a look at it again in the morning and see if I can figure out how to answer it.

Comment: @VitaminC, you can also up-vote these comments. Move your mouse cursor over the left corner of the comment and you'll se a hidden button.

Comment: That does not actually give reputation, it sort of just re-arranges the comments so that quality comments are not hidden by the "show more comments" button. But that is fine by me, if I truly cared about reputation I would not write nearly as many comments as I do. If my response fits into the comment character limit I find it is usually not detailed enough to serve as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I really do appreciate all the help you have given me though.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said that the OpenGL binding system is limiting and restrictive you where right, it is.
However, it is easy to get used to. Your workflow when dealing with GL objects consists basically of:

- Bind resource
- Use (draw/modify/query)
- Unbind resource

Now, going into specifics, how would you model a C++ class that encapsulate a VAO/VBO?
One very simple way, with implicit binding, could be:

```
class MyVAO {
public:

    void Draw()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawElements(...);
        // etc...
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

private:

    GLuint vb, ib, vao;
};

// Then in the client code:
MyVAO vao;
...
vao.Draw();
```

With explicit binding:

```
class MyVAO {
public:

    void Bind()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
    }

    void Unbind()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        glDrawElements(...);
        // etc...
    }

private:

    GLuint vb, ib, vao;
};

// Then in the client code:
MyVAO vao;
...
vao.Bind();
vao.Draw();
vao.Unbind();
```

The choice of explicit or implicit binding is yours. Implicit binding automates the work a bit, but it can be wasteful when you are sharing resources in the code. It can also lead to some hard to track bugs if you forget to bind/unbind inside the class implementation. Explicit binding allows you to do things like leaving a resource bound for a long time and use it for a while, but it can be a nightmare to debug cases when you forget to bing/unbind the resource yourself.

I personally tend to prefer the explicit binding though. I dislike having things happening behind the curtains. I prefer to know when a resource is current. But ultimately, you should choose the best fit for your project.

Comment: Thank you for the example, this class handling system was exactly what I was looking for.